# How to configure certificate authorities for a server?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a server and a client communicating via HTTPS. Java ssl standart is used.
During handshake, client receives *CertificateRequest* from the server.

In this message there is a list of *certificate_authorities*. This list contains only one authority. How to make server send other auhorities in request ?